# Selecting all the records based on filter criteria on 2 fields

Tags: text-processing, csv-simple

```
ABC,1234.5333,5733.9374,5673.352,352,2.346374,-0.6686874
XYZ,5463.674,93773.683,5734.874,432,-5.683423,-10.38393
AES,7436874.5743,937.6843,8464.5634,564,6.35739,10.6834
PQR,784945.464,57484.8647,57484.453,5764,-10.67484,5.74764
```

From the above csv file , I need to write shell script which will select all the records where the absolute values for any of the
last two fields[ ABS(6th field) or ABS(7th field) ] is > = 10.

As a result, my output should look like this:

```
XYZ,5463.674,93773.683,5734.874,432,-5.683423,-10.38393
AES,7436874.5743,937.6843,8464.5634,564,6.35739,10.6834
PQR,784945.464,57484.8647,57484.453,5764,-10.67484,5.74764
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `awk`. Something like can do the work (using only internal functions):

```
awk -F\, '{if (sqrt($(NF-1)*$(NF-1))>=10 || sqrt($NF*$NF)>=10 ) { print $0}}'  input_file
```

Comment: Why not simply: `awk -F\, 'sqrt($(NF-1)*$(NF-1))>=10 || sqrt($NF*$NF)>=10'` ?

Comment: @DanieleGrassini, also possible :)

Comment: all calculations in awk use floating point arithmetic so `sqrt(X*X)` is not necessarily exactly equal to `abs(X)` and so YMMV with this approach, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#FP-Math-Caution. In gawk on my system for example, `echo '0.6686874' | awk '{print sqrt($0*$0)}'` outputs `0.668687` instead of the `0.6686874` that was input.

Answer (score 2):

As you have implied you can use awk for this. You need to define your own function to get absolute values. so you can use something like this:

```
awk -F, 'function abs(a) {return a < 0 ? -a : a};(abs($6) >= 10 || abs($7) >= 10)' inputfile.txt 
XYZ,5463.674,93773.683,5734.874,432,-5.683423,-10.38393
AES,7436874.5743,937.6843,8464.5634,564,6.35739,10.6834
PQR,784945.464,57484.8647,57484.453,5764,-10.67484,5.74764
```

Comment: +1 for the `abs` function.  `(` in the or evaluation is not needed as the `;` in between the function and the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool that can parse `csv` data and filter rows, e.g.`python` with `csv` module or `csvsql` from `csvkit`.

```bash
csvsql -H --query 'select * from file where abs(f) > 10 or abs(g) > 10' file | sed 1d
```

(I pipe to `sed` to remove the output header row).

Output:

```
XYZ,5463.674,93773.683,5734.874,432.0,-5.683423,-10.38393
AES,7436874.5743,937.6843,8464.5634,564.0,6.35739,10.6834
PQR,784945.464,57484.8647,57484.453,5764.0,-10.67484,5.74764
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{c6=$6;c7=$7;sub(/^-/,"",c6);sub(/^-/,"",c7)} c6 >= 10 || c7 >= 10' data.csv
```

---

Do an absolute clone ( removing the eventual leading `-` sign ) on the desired fields and test them upon the limits.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (`mlr`) and its `filter` sub-command to filter out (extract) each record from your header-less CSV file whose penultimate or last field is 10 or larger in magnitude:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N filter 'abs($[NF-1]) >= 10 || abs($[NF]) >= 10' file
XYZ,5463.674,93773.683,5734.874,432,-5.683423,-10.38393
AES,7436874.5743,937.6843,8464.5634,564,6.35739,10.6834
PQR,784945.464,57484.8647,57484.453,5764,-10.67484,5.74764
```

As in `awk`, `NF` is the number of fields in the current record. With `$[NF]` we get the value of the last field, while `$[NF-1]` gives us the value of the penultimate field.

If the data had headers, you would drop the `-N` option and use the field names in place of `$[NF]` etc., as in

```bash
mlr --csv filter 'abs($fieldA) >= 10 || abs($fieldB) >= 10' file
```